# confused about the usage of apostrophe

Tags: apostrophe

I was confused about the usage of apostrophe. Can you please answer which one is correct and why?

1. Do you copy other's code?
2. Do you copy others' code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are ever unsure, rephrase as "of"

Do you mean "code of (many) others" or "code of (one) other"

If it means "code of others" then "others' code".  If you mean code of (one) other" then "other's".

I your context you probably mean "code of others", since you'd have said "another's code" if you had meant the singular. So "**others' code**

And since misplaced apostrophe is one of the most common mistakes that native English speakers make, most people will be very tolerant of mistakes by non-native speakers.

Answer (score 1):

It should be "others' code" (with the apostrophe after the 's', as the Saxon genitive is clearly about more than one other person's code).

If it were about a single other person, the sentence would read "Do you copy *an*other's code".

Both sentences seem a little old-fashioned to my ear. In my dialect, we'd say something like:

"Do you copy other people's code?" and
"Do you copy someone else's code?" respectively.